# Redirect to controller using JavaScript and MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im trying to redirect to a Controller from JavaScript using this line of code

```
 location.href = '/Dashboard/';
```

It redirects to the Dashboard but on my dashboard view this method is called when the document loads

```
 $.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet) {
    //do something with the dataset
 });
```

I then get this error.

```
POST http://localhost:1414/Dashboard/Dashboard/UsersGet 404 (Not Found)
```

I can see that dashboard is added to the url twice. How can I redirect to a Controller without this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Url` helper:

```
@Url.Action("UsersGet", "Dashboard")
```

Full code:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("UsersGet", "Dashboard")', {}, function (dataSet) {
    //do something with the dataset
 });
```

Routes in Asp .Net MVC don't work like in classic Asp.Net.

Comment: thanks @gdoron but can you please elaborate why should I use the Url.Action instead of just adding the forward slash :)

Comment: @JohandeKlerk. You know how routes work? they can be customized, that Url helper knows  how to handle them. In asp.net there wasn't such things. Anyway, **in MVC you work with actions and controlles, not URLS.** [Read more here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $.post("/Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet) {
    //do something with the dataset
 });
```

Add `/` to the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet) {
    //do something with the dataset
 });
```

should be

```
 $.post("/Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet) {
    //do something with the dataset
 });
```

Without '/' the url which you post will be appended to the current url.